# How can I get the remaining time left on a Unity coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am wondering how I could get the remaining time on a running coroutine. I want to run another coroutine off the remaining other coroutine. Sorta like this:

```
void test (){
    StartCoroutine(TestOne());
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){        // some way to get remaining time, or 
        StartCoroutine(TestTwo(time));  // something like this: 
                                        // float time = TestOne.GetRemainingTime();      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends a lot on what you are trying to do, but there is not a .GetRemainingTime() method in Unity.

A general solution is having a counter in your couroutine, something like...

```
float remainingTimeA = 0f;

IEnumerator MyRoutineA()
{
    float duration = 2.0f //Two seconds

    remainingTimeA = duration; //Set the remaining time as the duration
    while(remainingTimeA > 0f) //While there is still time
    {
        remainingTimeA -= Time.deltaTime; //Reduce the timer with time between previous and actual frame
        yield return null; //Wait for this frame to end
    }
}
```

What you can do is having a `remainingTimeA` variable that you can check if you need it. You initialize it on the coroutine with the duration you want to wait. And then use a while to manually create the waiting each frame.

`yield return null` waits for the end of the frame, instead of `new WaitForSeconds(duration)` you are just wainting each frame while you reduced your timer by `Time.deltaTime` that is the time between each frame. So if 1 second have passed since the start of the coroutine, remainingTimeA should be 1.0f.

I hope is clear.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make `test` a `IEnumerator`:

```
IEnumerator test (){

    yield return StartCoroutine(TestOne());  //wait until TestOne() is over 

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)); //wait until user press A

    yield return StartCoroutine(TestTwo(time));  //wait until TestTwo(time) is over

}
```

The last line could be only `StartCoroutine(TestTwo(time));` if you don't need the code to wait anything else.

This way, you don't need to know the remaining time, you just wait until it ends and then run everything else.